# Windows auth default domain prefix

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-authentication

Is there a way to change default domain prefix (DOMAIN\Username) when entering the username in windows auth prompt? I have a machine out of domain and I need to enter just username and password because entering prefix is a bit annoying. But by default it becomes MACHINENAME\Username.

Comment: If you are on the machine that isn't in a domain, there should be no need to specify the domain or machinename.

Comment: I think I expressed myself imprecisely. I mean I get auth window when I trying to get access to shared directory.